# OrderBy not working in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am using orderBy to order the drop down list but it is not working . Can someone please suggest on this ? Please let me know if you need any other information ..

```
<select class="selectbox form-control" class="form-control" data-ng-model="ctrl.task.delegateFromId" data-ng-options="user.marsId as user.fullName for user in ctrl.userList | orderBy:'fullName' ">
   <option value="">-- Select Area Owner --</option>
</select>
```

[here is plunker for this question 1st drop down order by is working but for 2nd it is not working](http://plnkr.co/edit/v11GlpKcgRV92psHOPD7?p=preview)

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: can you make a plnkr or a jsfiddle?

Comment: no .I do not see error ., Let me create pluker ..

Comment: here is plnker for this question - https://plnkr.co/edit/v11GlpKcgRV92psHOPD7?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is your problem but i put simple example.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
  var vm = this;
    vm.userList =JSON.parse('{"11":{"marsId":"11","firstName":"cc","lastName":"cc","fullName":"cc cc"},"12":{"marsId":"12","firstName":"aa","lastName":"aa","fullName":"aa aa"},"45":{"marsId":"45","firstName":"kk","lastName":"kk","fullName":"kk kk"}}');
  
  
  vm.userList2 = [];
for (var key in vm.userList) {
  var tempObj = "";
  tempObj = vm.userList[key];
  vm.userList2.push(tempObj);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
        <select class="selectbox form-control" class="form-control" data-ng-model="vm.task.delegateFromId" data-ng-options="user.marsId as user.fullName for user in vm.userList2 | orderBy:'fullName' ">
   <option value="">-- Select Area Owner --</option>
          
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your response but my user list has a little but different structure .Can you please take a look of plunker created by me . plnkr.co/edit/v11GlpKcgRV92psHOPD7?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

**Dear**, if you want names to be sorted alphabetically then try this :

```
<select class="selectbox form-control" class="form-control" data-ng-model="ctrl.task.delegateFromId" data-ng-options="user.marsId as user.fullName for user in ctrl.userList | orderBy:'toString()' ">
   <option value="">-- Select Area Owner --</option>
</select>
```

1. You need to add ng-model to correctly make the binding works for a list of strings.
2. You can use toString() to sort if the input contains a list of strings. Since the expression of orderBy can be a Getter function. The result of this function will be sorted using the <, =, > operator.

**Thanks & Cheers**

Comment: I've created a plunker for this . can you please check . plnkr.co/edit/v11GlpKcgRV92psHOPD7?p=preview